# file_exists(...) not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to use `file_exists()` function in wordpress but unable to get expected result.

```
if(file_exists(WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/sinetiks-schools/images/t_1.jpg')){
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "not";
    }
```

Comment: use `plugins_url()` instead of `WP_PLUGIN_URL`

Comment: Not working even if the path is correct in both cases plugins_url() and WP_PLUGIN_URL the control goes in else part

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one . i hope your problem will be solved

```
    $image = get_template_directory() . "/images/" . get_the_title() . ".png";
$image2 = get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/" . get_the_title() . ".png";

if (file_exists($image)) 
{
        echo "<img src=" . $image2 . ">";
} 
else
 {
        echo the_title("<h1 class='title'>","</h1>");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
if(file_exists(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/sinetiks-schools/images/t_1.jpg')){

}
```

Make sure you are getting correct path from `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`

you can find more information on plugin_dir_path function [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path)